# Time required to list off keys in a B-tree in sorted order?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, big-o, b-tree

I want to sort a long list, so I put all the elements into a B-tree (each element takes O(log n) time to insert).

Once sorted, I need to read back the elements.

Do you know how it is done how long it is to read all the objects in a B-tree?

Thanks!

Comment: You can put elements in a B-tree in linear time. You can't insert in log time. Sorting takes nlog(n) time anyways, and an in-order traversal (which is what you're after) takes linear time. Your best bet is to use `list.sort()` and print the result

Comment: Isn't a single insertion O(_log_ n))?  So creating the entire b-tree would be O(n _log_ n), which is the same time complexity of Python's built-in sort.

Comment: Yes I was thinking of this when written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over all of the elements in a B-tree in sorted order in time O(n) by using a modification of an inorder traversal.  You would do this recursively as follows:

```
To list off all elements of tree T in sorted order:
    Let the children of T be C0, C1, C2, ... Cn
    Let the keys of T be K1, K2, ..., Kn

    Output C0
    For i from 1 to n:
       Output Ki
       Recursively list all elements of Ci in order.
```

This takes time O(n), because each key is visited exactly once. (As a fun exercise, try comparing this to how a standard inorder traversal works!)  Since it takes time O(n log n) to build a B-tree from unsorted data, this sorting algorithm takes time O(n log n).  You can think of it as a modification of [tree sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_sort) that uses a B-tree rather than a BST.

If the B-tree is stored on-disk, this does not have very good caching performance.  You would be better off using a [B+ tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B+_tree), which is specifically designed to optimize for inorder traversals and range searches.

Hope this helps!